# Find independent solutions for triple eigenvalues with defect $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble understanding defective eigenvalues and associated linear systems. I apologize in advance if my formatting is poorly executed.
Given the following problem:
$$
x' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & -2 & -3\\
2 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
x
$$
I find that it has an eigenvalue of $$\lambda = 1$$ with k(multiplicity) = 3.
Solving for the eigenvectors I get two independent solutions 
$$
v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\0\\2
\end{bmatrix}, 
v_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\2\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
but I'm having trouble after that. Since it has a defect of $1$, I solved the following equations.
$$
(A - \lambda I)^2v_3 = 0\\ 
(A - \lambda I)v_3 = v_2\\
(A - \lambda I)v_2 = v_1\\
$$
Since the matrix squared was a zero matrix, I set $v_3$ to $[1\, 0\, 0]^T$ and solved for the other two vectors. Since the first row of $$(A-\lambda I)$$ is all zeros, it is impossible to end with the two independent solutions that I solved for in the first step (as the book suggests I should) using this method.

Can someone help me find the error in my approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep $$
(A - \lambda I)^2v_3 = 0\\ 
(A - \lambda I)v_3 = v_2\\
$$
but then $v_2$ is already a genuine eigenvector, as $(A -I)v_2 = (A-I)^2 v_3 = 0 v_3 = 0.$
Then $v_1$ needs to be a genuine eigenvector but linearly independent of $v_2.$  For your choice $v_3 = (1,0,0)^t,$  we are forced to $v_2 = (0,-2,2)^T.$ We may then choose $v_1.$ Since our $v_2$ is the difference of the eigenvectors you first mentioned, we might as well take $v_1$ to be a multiple of their sum, or $v_1 = (-6,2,2)^T/2 = (-3,1,1)^T$

The new basis matrix is
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-3&0&1 \\
1 & -2&0 \\
1&2&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with
$$
P^{-1} =
\frac{1}{4}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&2&2 \\
0 & -1&1 \\
4&6&6
\end{array}
\right)
$$
You get $P^{-1}AP = J,$ where your matrix is $A$ and $J$ is the Jordan form. The direction you actually use is $P J P^{-1} = A,$ where 
$$
J =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0 \\
0 & 1&1 \\
0&0&1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so you should check, by hand, that my claimed $P J P^{-1} = A$ really works. Note that you may pull out the factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ until you multiply with it at the very end, this way you are not carrying around denominators all the way and possibly causing errors.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help. Just to be sure I'm understanding correctly, $v_1$ can be any combination of the ordinary eigenvectors that I solved for in the first step given that it is linearly independent with the two other generalized eigenvectors?

Comment: @Jay yes. If you mistakenly made $v_1$ a multiple  $v2,$ it would turn out that the matrix I have been calling $P$ would not be invertible